# Angular 2 Flash Message Service not working

Tags: angular, angular-cli, mean-stack

I am new to mean stack. My Project is working fine but just after adding Flash Message Service and trying to use flash message service by referring

https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular2-flash-message

and while doing this I am getting this issue

```
ERROR in SETeamProject/angular-src/node_modules/angular2-flash-message/node_modules/rxjs/observable/dom/WebSocketSubject.d.ts (44,5): Property 'lift' in type 'WebSocketSubject<T>' is not assignable to the same property in base type 'AnonymousSubject<T>'.
  Type '<R>(operator: Operator<T, R>) => WebSocketSubject<R>' is not assignable to type '<R>(operator: Operator<T, R>) => Observable<T>'.
    Type 'WebSocketSubject<R>' is not assignable to type 'Observable<T>'.
      Types of property 'operator' are incompatible.
        Type 'Operator<any, R>' is not assignable to type 'Operator<any, T>'.
          Type 'R' is not assignable to type 'T'.
```

webpack: Failed to compile.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution to this so I thought to update it as an answer. I had to delete node_modules in angular directory and do npm install and it worked fine.

Hope this helps.